# ASP.net Web API: Why are controllers created per request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Mike Wasson's article "[Dependency Injection for Web API Controllers](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver)" on www.asp.net says:

> **Dependenecy Scope and Controller Lifetime**
>
> Controllers are created per request...

Am I correct in understanding that ASP.NET Web API creates a new controller instance (and satisfies its dependencies) for each incoming request?

Is this approach not wasteful in that it creates and destroys many instances of the controller when in theory a single instance could be used for all requests?

Comment: Theoretically, sure; but object creation (and destruction) in .NET isn't expensive at all. Controllers in ASP.NET MVC (and WebAPI) are relatively simple objects, certainly the instantiation of old Web Form's `Page` for each request is probably far more expensive.

Comment: There are also practical problems with keeping a stateful controller: you'd need extra work to perform separate per-request cleanup (e.g. DB connections) and per-instance cleanup (e.g. Controller state). There are also issues with reentrancy and concurrency (ASP.NET uses a different thread for each request). It's certainly simpler and more reliable to have a single controller instance for each request.

Comment: Since HTTP is a stateless protocoll it's a natural way to handle requests in a stateless manner ...

Comment: In some dependency injection frameworks such as Castle you can use pooled lifecycles, where the DI framework automatically initializes n resource of your dependency and keeps them in a pool that are reused whenever someone asks for that service (likely in a round-robin fashion). Keep in mind of pitfalls such as if the destruction/finalization of that service normally would e.g. end a transaction that would finish the operation properly, in Castle you can get around this by implementing an interface method that is called for each recycling.

Comment: @Dai (as long as appropriate conventions are followed, including not putting a bunch of work in the constructor!)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A controller contains information (state) about the incoming request.

If you had only one controller to handle many requests then they would all be confused and users would likely get some strange results.

Comment: Thanks @rowan-freeman. Can you elaborate? What state does the controller contain about the request?

Comment: @urig Well, for one, the [Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.request(v=vs.118).aspx) property.

Comment: It didn't need to be that way. All of the request state initially comes from the HttpContext, which is effectively thread local storage. But I'm happy with this choice, as it reduces the chance of problems caused by instance fields.

Comment: "All of the request state initially comes from the HttpContext": this is wrong. Web Api uses its own action/controller/request contexts, populated by the framework upon each incoming request and does not depend on the `System.Web` dll. (i.e. you can self-host a Web Api project).

Comment: not convinced, if we are not maintaining any instance variables/state in controller then how "users would likely get some strange results." ?

Comment: You may or may not be doing so directly, but the framework is. A controller has a `ControllerContext` property, an `HttpContext` property, a `Request` property, a `Response` property, a `Session` property and a `User` property. These properties contain state about the **current HTTP request**, the user, the sessions, and also what will be returned to the user. If you try to use a single Controller object, a user could potentially see the route and user of a completely different user, or maybe just a server error.

Comment: @RowanFreeman Would be nice if you added your last comment as part of the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

If it wasn't recreated each request you'd effectively have a singleton or static class meaning you'd need to handle resetting the classes state on exceptions and all sorts of other cases. The result would almost certainly mean bugs.

The overhead for creating a new context each time is a small price to pay for better code maintainability.