# How can I generate a random object that's available in all methods in a controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Here's the code that I have:

```
namespace WebRole.Controllers
{

    [RoutePrefix("api/WordAPI")]
    public class WordAPIController : BaseController
    {

        [AuthorizeRoles(ERole.Super, ERole.Admin, ERole.WordAdmin)]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Wapi/{source}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Wapi(string source)
        {
```

What I would like to do is to generate a random object every time that a method is called and then be able to use it in the method.

So I would like to do something like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

And have it available everywhere in my code.

Any suggestions on where I could place and use random so it's available to all methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is to declare a class variable that's instantiated inside the controllers constructor.

```
namespace WebRole.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/WordAPI")]
    public class WordAPIController : BaseController
    {
        private Random random;
        public WordAPIController()
        {
            this.random = new Random();
        }

        [AuthorizeRoles(ERole.Super, ERole.Admin, ERole.WordAdmin)]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Wapi/{source}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Wapi(string source)
        {
```

Does this mean that every request to the controller use the same random? [No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175626/asp-net-web-api-why-are-controllers-created-per-request), or most likely not. The controllers are created per request and a random is therefore created for each request as well.