# Is controller class instance created and a respective instance method is called at each request in ASP.NET Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

Are web application type and controller the same things in ASP.NET Framework?

In the **CLR via C#** there is the following excerpt present:

> **When future clients make requests of an already running web application**, ASP.NET doesn’t create a
>   new AppDomain; instead, it uses the existing AppDomain, **creates a new instance of the web
>   application’s type**, and starts calling methods. The methods will already be JIT-compiled into native
>   code, so the performance of processing all subsequent client requests is excellent.

Does it mean that controller class instance is created and a respective instance method is called at each request in ASP.NET Framework?

E.g. if I have the following controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("prefix")]
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("something/{id}")]
    public string GetSomething(int id)
    {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

Does it mean that each time I request the `prefix/something/47` (any number here instead of the 47 and host before the url should be present) a new instance of the `FooController` is created and the  `FooController.GetSomething` method is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a new Controller instance is used per request. As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25175814/10479955) answer to an older question, new instances are used to avoid potential state issues with handling multiple requests.

Comment: That is helpful. Thank you. I will try to accept your answer asap.

Comment: this article can also help you understand it more - https://hogaf.github.io/archive/2014/11/13/why-asp.net-requests-are-processed-sequentially.